# QML Text element with rich text: How to adjust vertical position of an <img>

Tags: html, css, qt, qml

I have a Text element with some HTML content which contains an `<img>` tag. I want to adjust the baseline of this image since it displays a rasterized latex math formula. Detecting the baseline within the image is another task. This question is how to adjust the vertical position of the image when I know how many pixels I have to move the image.

In HTML, I can use relative positioning. Since Qt only supports [a subset of CSS](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/richtext-html-subset.html#css-properties), I have to use different CSS properties. However, *none* of them seem to be working when displaying HTML using a QML Text element! What's wrong?

```
Text {
    text: 'test <img style="padding: 100px" src="latex/182.png"/>'
}
```

This displays exactly the same compared to leaving out the style attribute. It's like QML ignores style attributes. Does QML use another (even tinier) HTML engine?

I already found out that images are only supported in the "rich text" mode (there also is the "styled text" mode which doesn't support images but other HTML tags like `<b>` and `<i>`).

Comment: This is an old question, so the answer below is perhaps outdated. Either way, there's (now?) a `textFormat` property on the Text element that I had to set to `Text.RichText` for my use case. Then the basic CSS properties and table elements worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed similar problem by using HTML `<table>`s. They are better supported in Qt.

Comment: It's worth a try. However, this will introduce a new problem: text wrapping... I can't image how to solve this... Or do I understand you wrong? You want to wrap the whole text in a table (so there is one cell with the text before the image, one cell with the image and one cell with the text after the image, or more if there are more images) or just wrap each image in a table with a single cell?

Comment: I've ended with wrapping each image inside single-cell tables. CSS `float` seems working right, at least in `<table>` element.

Comment: I don't understand... If I wrap the image in a table with a single cell, the table introduces a new paragraph, which is not what I want. If I specify `float:right` or `left` on the table, it is floating next to the text of the paragraph. Example: `text before <table><tr><td><img src="test.png"/></td></tr></table> text after` Can Qt display tables in-line?

Comment: Normally, we would specify `display:inline` on the table, but Qt doesn't support this CSS property. :(

Comment: Ugh, idea was to use `float: both`, but right now, I've realized that QT doesn't support (in my app I've needed only `float: left`) :(

Comment: P.S. As last resort you may try to use webkit (QML WebView) or try to use font metrics and make padding in images by hand.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but this seems to be heavy-wheight. I'd rather implement a minimal Text element by myself which can vertically adjust `<img>` positions... The rest of the HTML support I need is very limited: only bold and italics. So this should be a 1-hour project. This can even be done within QML: I could split the text in words and place an item for every word in a Flow container. Images become items with an Image element inside (which uses the `y` property to adjust its position) and words are just Text elements. [Like this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-positioners.html#flow)

Comment: Yup, this solved the problem. However, to adjust the line height of the text, Flow isn't the right layout element. I wrote an own one to solve this. (Flow has `spacing` which specifies both the horizontal and the vertical spacing.)